# Rails Migration Rollback: How to delete generated migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I generated a new migration using command,

```
rails g migration add_stdf_to_sds blahblah:string
```

I have not used rake:db migrate till now and I don't want to use it because I don't want this migration to happen, how can I delete my generated migration?

I know about rollback, but I haven't used db:migrate till now so it won't work. (I guess).

Comment: `rails d migration add_stdf_to_sds`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rails d migration add_stdf_to_sds
```

In general 'rails d' which stands for 'rails destroy' is a great way to undo any command that a generator has performed.

Answer (score 1):

rails g migration adds a file in db/migrations that starts with a timestamp. Delete that file from the filesystem.